# SQL sum error in ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to make a simple dummy database, but I encountered a problem while trying to query this:

```
SELECT
    k.id_customer,
    k.name_customer,
    k.lastname_customer,
    r.date_bill,
    sum(p.price_product*us.quantity) AS TOTAL_PRICE  
FROM
    product p,
    bill r,
    item us,
    customer k  
WHERE
    k.id_customer=1
    AND k.id_customer=r.customer_ID_customer 
    AND us.bill_ID_bill=r.ID_bill
    AND p.ID_product=us.product_ID_product  
GROUP BY k.id_customer
```

ORACLE states out the following error:

> ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression

I have tried doing the same query only with the sum and it worked, but I'd like to add the name of the customer and the date on the bill.

Comment: Do you need to compute the sum for each date separately, or do you need to sum them over all dates? If over all dates, then do NOT include `r.date_bill` in `group by`. Instead, REMOVE it from `select`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the expressions that are not aggregate functions must be part of the `GROUP BY`. Try with:

```
SELECT
    k.id_customer,
    k.name_customer,
    k.lastname_customer,
    r.date_bill,
    sum(p.price_product*us.quantity) AS TOTAL_PRICE  
FROM
    product p,
    bill r,
    item us,
    customer k  
WHERE
    k.id_customer=1
    AND k.id_customer=r.customer_ID_customer 
    AND us.bill_ID_bill=r.ID_bill
    AND p.ID_product=us.product_ID_product  
GROUP BY k.id_customer,
    k.name_customer,
    k.lastname_customer,
    r.date_bill
```

Also, consider not to use that old syntax for your JOINS, it's more likely to inadvertently introduce *CROSS JOINs*. It would be something like:

```
...
FROM table1
  INNER JOIN table2
    ON (table1.column1 = table2.column2)
```

Comment: It worked,
thank you very much for such a fast solution.

Comment: @IbrahimBeganović you can select this as the accepted answer then.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding you need to include all expressions from the SELECT clause that are not a group function, so the following should work.

```
    SELECT k.id_customer,k.name_customer,k.lastname_customer,r.date_bill,sum(p.price_product*us.quantity) AS TOTAL_PRICE
    FROM product p,bill r,item us,customer k
    WHERE k.id_customer=1 AND k.id_customer=r.customer_ID_customer AND us.bill_ID_bill=r.ID_bill AND p.ID_product=us.product_ID_product
    GROUP BY k.id_customer,
k.name_customer,
k.lastname_customer,
r.date_bill
```

Comment: That works,
thank you for replying in such a short notice.